# How to delete multiple records using a check box in php?

Tags: php, checkbox, sql-delete

I have check several solution on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to crack the code. I am trying to  delete multiple records using a check boxes but when I click the delete button it doesn't get the array I have created.

```
<?php


  // Connect to the database
      include("dbconnect.inc");

  // Build SQL statment that selects a student's modules
  $sql = "select * from student;";

  $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

      $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
  if (isset($_GET['delete']))
 {


 $test = $_GET['test'];

 $i = 0 ;
 $sql= "DELETE FROM student  ";
 foreach ($test as $item_studentid)
{

$i ++;
if ($i == 1)

{

$sql .= "WHERE studentid = " .mysql_real_escape_string($item_studentid)."";
echo "KJ";
}
else
{
$sql.= " OR studentid = "  .mysql_real_escape_string($item_studentid)."";

}

}
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;



}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Students</title>
<head>
enter code here<body>
<form name="frmStudents" action="" method="post">
    <table border='1'>
    <tr><th colspan='11' align='center'>Students</th></tr>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>PassCode</th><th>DOB</th><th>First Name</th><th>Surname</th>
    <th>House No.</th><th>Town</th><th>County</th><th>Country</th><th>PostCode</th>                        
   <th>Select</th></tr>
   <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {         
    echo "<tr><td> $row[studentid] </td><td> $row[password] </td>";
    echo "<td> $row[dob] </td><td>$row[firstname]</td>";
    echo "<td> $row[lastname] </td><td> $row[house] </td>";
    echo "<td> $row[town] </td><td>$row[county]</td>";
    echo "<td> $row[country] </td><td>$row[postcode]</td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='test'> </td></tr>";            
   }

 ?>
    </table>

<input name="delete" value="Delete Selected" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much... i sincerely apologist i have copied the wrong code it is now edited am new to php i have been debugging for a few hour am i as unable to get the value from the array.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='test'> </td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='{$row['studentid']}'></td></tr>";
```

you will then have a `$_POST['delete']` array you can process

Comment: +1 Looks promising. I for one, couldn't wrap my head around OP's code. Must be all those Espressos; mind's aburst.

Comment: asks question, get answers, deletes account - odd

Comment: I thought the same thing too. "Fly-by-night" *hmph.* Oh well, you got a +1 out of it ;-)

Comment: but no green tick! what will i put on my CV if not all my S.O answers?  :-)

Comment: Call it "pro-bono", some like that type 'o stuff.

Comment: im thinking "charity work" would be a great section for S.O. "washed the leppas, answered S.O questions" sounds simular

Comment: Yeah, when an OP asks a question, there should either be a "this is a pro question (not pro bono)" or "I'm a one-night-stand, call me quick & dirty" option.

Comment: OP's question is total irony though. Didn't know how to delete entries, but sure knew how to delete the account. (Total A-hole).

Comment: thats iron man's new super power in the next movie

Comment: Let me guess who'll be playing his dad; Ozzy. Just like Jack Sparrow's dad, Keith. hehe